# How to set notification receiver in android foreground service without notification of service running ...like Whatsapp and Telegram?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, service, push-notification

I am developing a chat messenger like whatsapp and telegram and i want a foreground receiver for messages to show in notification bar ... but in the latest version of Android we should set a notification to tell that our service is running in the foreground , but in famous messengers we doesn't see this notification ... I want to know how can i do this

This is my Message_Receiver class that extends service class

```
class Message_Receiver : Service() {

private var mSocket: Socket? = null
lateinit var username : String
lateinit var notifmanag : NotificationManagerCompat
lateinit var notifbuilder : NotificationCompat.Builder
val CHANNEL_ID = "Messages"

lateinit var respondData : JSONObject
lateinit var type : String
lateinit var roomname : String
lateinit var roompic : String
lateinit var sender : String
lateinit var senderpic : String
lateinit var msg : String
lateinit var timeStamp : String


override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
    return null
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags2: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    //Service().startForeground(11,notifbuilder.build())

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags2, startId)
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    mSocket?.disconnect()
}

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    username = MySharedPreference("profile",this).load("username","string") as String

    // Notification preconfigurations //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    notifmanag = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "Message_Channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
        channel.description = "Message_Channel"
        //notifmanag = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)
        notifmanag.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
    val intent2 = Intent(this, RoomActivity::class.java).apply {
        flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
    }
    val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent2, 0)

    // Conncect to socket //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////   

    // Listener for new messages ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    val onNewMessage = Emitter.Listener {
        respondData = it[0] as JSONObject
        
        sender = respondData.getString("sender")
        
        notifbuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
        if (roomname == "PRIVATE"){
            notifbuilder.setContentTitle(username)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        }else{
            notifbuilder.setContentTitle(roomname)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        }
        when (type.toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT)){
            "TEXT" -> notifbuilder.setContentText(msg)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.nearoom_icon2)


            "PHOTO" -> notifbuilder.setContentText("Photo : " + msg)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.nearoom_icon2)


            "VIDEO" -> notifbuilder.setContentText("Video : " + msg)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.nearoom_icon2)
        }

        notifmanag.notify(12,notifbuilder.build())

    }

    mSocket?.on("new message",onNewMessage)

}
```

}

Comment: You can use firebase to manage notifications, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging
I hope this can help you

Comment: @JefersonMacedo Yes i know a little about it but i want to save my registered users and chats history in my databases ...

Comment: I think you can do this if you implement onMessageReceived
and pass the information you want in the notification data property
and inside onMessageReceived method you can save it in your database
see here https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those Apps doesn't use Services, so they don't need any Persistent Notification in the Statusbar. Push Notifications (when a message arrives) uses Firebase and the Backup at 02:00am uses JobScheduler set to that time.

Comment: Thank you for your answering ... my only question is can i use the fcm for pushing my notifications but doesn't use register and databases from firebase ?

Comment: Firebase need to store an (its own) ID for each of your Users, in this way you can send Push Notification to a specific user (using your ID) and Firebase translates your ID in one of those already stored in its Database

Comment: Thanks ... I fix it